# How do I stop the NetworkManager in Ubuntu 13.10?

Tags: network-manager

I tried as root

```
service network-manager stop
```

and

```
/etc/init.d/network-manager stop
```

But that doesen't exist.

And:

```
killall NetworkManager
```

but it seems to restart immediately.

How do I stop it???

---

EDIT:
I filed a new Question that describes more, what my problem is:
[How do I stop the NetworkManager in Ubuntu 13.10 without using the service command?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/426631/)

Comment: Why are you wanting to stop Network Manager?

Comment: I want to start a mesh node on my laptop using batman-adv, batctl bridge-utils [with this script](http://freifunk.in-kiel.de/wiki/Eigenen_Rechner_in_das_Freifunk-Netz) and the NetworkManager is doing *stuff*

Comment: Hmm. So, now title says that command line is not allowed, but contents says that all you tried was using command line. And even questions at the end are related to command line.

Comment: @rubo77: You have edited the question to ask a different question by putting restrictions. There is already an answer which would render that as incorrect (and probably foolish as well). As such you should leave this question closed and ask a different and new question for your needs.. I also trust you to roll-back the edit you made... :-)

Comment: Wild Man's answer was foolish from the start, cause I stated from the beginning, that the command he suggested didn't work. So I didn't change the meaning of my question, but I will roll it back and ask a new question anyway ;)

Comment: I rolled it back and posted the real problem here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/426631/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Control+Alt+T will open the terminal then enter one of the following commands.

```
sudo service network-manager stop
```

will stop network manager.

```
sudo service network-manager start
```

will start network manager.

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

will restart network manager.

Comment: That didn't work! That's why I asked. I edited the topic of my question.

Comment: I found a link that says there may be a bug in 13.10 and if you use sudo in front of all the commands like I have them written in the answer then they will work. Even if you are root you still have to use sudo. <http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2181441>

Comment: folowup: http://askubuntu.com/questions/426631/