# How do I stop the NetworkManager in Ubuntu 13.10 without using the service command?

Tags: network-manager, services

Usually this works as root

```
service network-manager stop
```

But last time it didn't. There was some message like "no such service". Strangely today, after a reboot it works!

Yesterday I also tried:

```
/etc/init.d/network-manager stop
```

But that doesen't exist.

And:

```
killall NetworkManager
```

but it seems to restart immediately.

*Wild Man* found a link that says there may be a bug in 13.10 and if you use sudo in front of all the commands like I have them written in the answer then they will work. Even if you are root you still have to use sudo. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2181441
Or Why could the service command fail?

How do I definitely stop NetworkManager, even if the service command doesn't work?

Comment: Try `sudo stop network-manager` or `sudo stop --system network-manager`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try closing all NetworkManager processes via the "system manager" tool. It's similar to "Task Manager" in Windows.